i had an error in pycharm(using django) it says unresolved reference 'post'
in my views.py file i imported my "post" model from my models.py file(both files are in the same directory). i have used the "post" model two times in my views.py(in two different functions), in first function theres no problem but in second one it raises an error.  its says [unresolved references 'post']. when i ignore it and run server to check wether it works or not, its riases another error in my browser [cannot access local variable 'post' where it is not associated with a value]. i dont really get it.
i would really appreciate it if you help me.
I've uploaded my moleds.py, views.py source code blow...
# this is my views.py 
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import post

# Create your views here.
def posts_list(request):
    posts = post.objects.all().order_by("-date")
    return render(request, 'app1/posts_list.html', {"posts": posts})
def post_page(request, slug):
    post = post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'app1/post_page.html', {"post": post})


# this is my models.py 
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


You are getting the error because post is a reserved keyword in python
So, here is the updated code:
def post_page(request, slug):
    post_hello = post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'app1/post_page.html', {"post_hello": post_hello})

you can change the name post_hello as per your choice

thanks for your time and respond brother. i don't understand why the error didn't show up when i had one method(function) with the word 'post'?

I'm learning django using Dave Gray tutorial, i write the code step by step with Dave(tutorial), my confusion shows when Dave didn't get the same error as me, after that i decided to copy all app files from Dave source code and paste it in mine to pass the error in continue the tutorial. surprisingly not only my problem didn't solve but alsoo i get a new error. really over whelming lol.

my apps.py files code:                     ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                    from django.apps import AppConfig
class PostsConfig(AppConfig):
default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
name = 'posts'

my new error in terminal while running server: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'posts'. Check that 'app1.apps.PostsConfig.name' is correct.

change the name from post and try

in post_page you can't use post = post.objects.get(slug=slug) post as a name
